# Marshal unsigned char** in c#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to marshall unsigned char** in order to call the method  from C#.

i make an dllexport from c++

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec(dllexport) void ConvertToByte(char *filename,unsigned char** data)

  {
      char temp[100];
      sprintf(temp,filename);
       BITMAPINFO *info;
      *data=(unsigned char *)LoadDIBitmap(temp, &info);
  }
```

and here is the dllimport

```
[DllImport("bmpToByte.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void ConvertToByte(string pame, byte[] data);
```

I want to take the byte[] data (image) from here as a result.
but i can't take it.

Answer (score 1):

try using ref, haven't tried myself

```
    [DllImport("bmpToByte.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void ConvertToByte(string pame, ref byte[] data);
```